# Returning a pointer back from a dll/shared-library causes seg-fault

Tags: c++, pointers, plugins, shared-libraries

I'm writing a small plugin system for a program. Some parts of it are done already, loading the file and calling the constructor function works.

In one of the functions I need to pass some (class-)pointers back to the handler, that's where I get a seg-fault.

in program:

```
class RenderInterface {
    public:
        RenderInterface();
        virtual ~RenderInterface();

        void RegisterBufferInterface(BufferInterface* interface)
        {
             bInterface = interface; // <---- this is where segfault occurs
        }
        void RegisterCameraInterface(CameraInterface* interface){}
        void RegisterRenderInterface(RenderInterface* interface){}

        static RenderInterface* GetSingletonPtr()
        {
            return _singleton;
        }

    private:
        static RenderInterface* _singleton;

        BufferInterface* bInterface;
        CameraInterface* cInterface
        RenderInterface* rInterface;
};
```

**RenderInterface::_singleton is set to 0 elsewhere.**

in registration function (in dll):

```
class BInterface : public BufferInterface {
    public:
        ... various stuff ....
}

class GLPlugin : public Plugin {
    public:
        Plugin() : bInterface(0) {}
        ~Plugin(){}

        void Initialize() // <--- is called after dll has been loaded
        {
            bInterface = new BInterface();

            InterfaceManager::GetSingletonPtr()->RegisterBufferInterface(bInterface); // segfault
            // register other stuff
        }
    private:
        BufferInterface* bInterface;
};
```

What am I missing for this to work? Is there another way to do it?

Edit: missed the * after BufferInterface while simplifying the code, thanks Luchian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it crashes because you never initialize your singleton:

```
static RenderInterface* GetSingletonPtr()
{
    return _singleton;
}
```

I'm assuming you initialize `_singleton` to `NULL` in your implementation file, in which case you'd need:

```
static RenderInterface* GetSingletonPtr()
{
    if ( !_singleton )
        _singleton = new RenderInterface;
    return _singleton;
}
```

Some other hints:

- asses other options before using singletons
- implementing a destructor usually means you also need a copy constructor and an assignment operator (the rule of three)
- if your class truly is a singleton, shouldn't the constructor be `private`?
- `bInterface = new BInterface();` is illegal, since `bInterface` is an object, not a pointer.

Comment: Thank you, that really helped me. I really forgot to set the singleton and couldn't find my mistake in 3 days!

Comment: static _singleton = new RenderInterface; can replace the if statement, and no need to worry about a nULL either

Comment: @OrgnlDave not always. Not if 1RenderInterface` depends on other stuff that is only known at runtime. It's usually done like this for a reason.

Comment: so what you're saying is, you're doing it this way because something else might initialize it? not very singleton-ish, but I suppose it works for that